# How to build a blog using next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, blogs, next.js

I'm new to web development, recently I want to build my own blog. I use Next.js to host my pages, I have already got the skeleton done, but there are still some significant problems.

1. How to render pages from markdown file? I just don't know how others do this. Do I have to use fs in the 'server.js' file and respond to certain request by md file? Or there are other ways?
2. If step 1 was completed, I wonder if I have `<img>` tags in my markdown file which refer to some local pictures, how can I render those?

Comment: Hi, this is extremely broad. In fact, I have built a Next,js based Blog. and I can assure you it is not a one page answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer 1. You can use the `npm` package [`markdown-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) .

But I strongly recommend using Docusorous or [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) for this purpose. Both have your requirement inbuilt.

Secondly, for Images - You can always include them in Markdown and they will be converted to JSX using [`markdown-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) .